# Nodejs 'res is not defined' inside require

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, require

For my api I want to require  a separate file to set a cookie (using cookie-parser). However `res` or `req` are not passed to the required file...

index.js

```
 app.get('/api/user/:username', function(req, res) {   
 urlUsername = req.params.username;
 require('./set/cookie')
  });
```

set/cookie.js

```
res.cookie('login_session', urlUsername) // returns 'res' not defined
```

As you can see to partially overcome this problem I set `urlUsername` which works. But surely there has to be another way :) ?

Thanks

Comment: is that the full contents of your `./set/cookie.js` file?

Comment: It is obvious that res is undefined in cookie.js you can set cookie inside app.get or declare a function in cookie.js which takes res from app.get. then you can do your task  inside that function

Comment: This has been written really badly...Node is not like PHP where you can simply define variables before a require and have the file inherit them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to modify your code like this

======= set/cookie.js ==========

```
module.exports = function(res) { // accept res parameter
  res.cookie('login_session', urlUsername)
};
```

=========== index.js ===========

```
app.get('/api/user/:username', function(req, res) {   
  urlUsername = req.params.username;
  require('./set/cookie')(res); // pass res to module
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use "**module.exports**" in the module you created as require returns an object with the same name.

Comment: you need to use "module.exports" as require returns an object with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your cookie.js file so that it creates an object that has the ability to cache, and that you can pass 'res' object to, so that it is available in scope

For instance, your cookie.js should look like the following:

```
module.exports.cookie = function(res){
    return {
        cache: function(){
            /*your cookie code*/
            return res.cookie('login_session', urlUsername);
        }
    };
}
```

This returns an object that has a cache method, and that has the response object passed to it. You would then invoke this by calling:

```
app.get('/api/user/:username', function(req, res) {   
    urlUsername = req.params.username;
    var cookie = require('./set/cookie').cookie(res);
    cookie.cache();
});
```

Comment: updated my code, the cookie cache function needed a return statement I believe